# Android - Getting wrong TimeZone abbreviations? Understanding CET vs CEST

Tags: android, timezone, android-date, java.util.calendar

I would like to print the correct **TimeZone abbreviation of a Date** in Android but I'm a little confused.

As far as I know in the **"Europe/Budapest" TimeZone** we have **"Standard Time" and "Daylight Saving Time"** - So the abbreviation for a date **during summer in this TimeZone should print CEST** (Central European Summer Time) while **during winter it should print CET** (Central European Time)

So far I made the following function:

1. I make a timestamp.
2. I make a Date object from the given timestamp.
3. I make a Calendar instance.
4. I set the Calendar's time parameter the previous Date object I created.
5. I set the Calendar's TimeZone as the following: "Europe/Budapest"

I run this function with a **summer** and a **winter** timestamp and the output is:

```
TIME_ = = = Winter date = = = 
TIME_ ts: 1701687285000
TIME_ date: Mon Dec 04 11:54:45 GMT+01:00 2023
TIME_ calendar's timezone: Central European Standard Time
TIME_ calendar's date: Mon Dec 04 11:54:45 GMT+01:00 2023

TIME_ = = = Summer date = = = 
TIME_ ts: 1688205285000
TIME_ date: Sat Jul 01 11:54:45 GMT+02:00 2023
TIME_ calendar's timezone: Central European Standard Time
TIME_ calendar's date: Sat Jul 01 11:54:45 GMT+02:00 2023
```

Both of the dates have **"Central European Standard Time" but it is wrong isn't it?**
The winter date should have **"Central European Time" since the summer date is CEST while the winter date is CET.**

---

Code of the function:

```
   fun printDate(label: String, ts: Long ) {
        Log.i("TIME_", "= = = " + label + " = = = ")
        val date = Date(ts)
        Log.i("TIME_", "ts: " + ts)
        Log.i("TIME_", "date: " + date)
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.time = date
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Budapest")
        Log.i("TIME_", "calendar's timezone: " + cal.timeZone.getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH))
        Log.i("TIME_", "calendar's date: " + cal.time)
    }
```

What am I miscalculating here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First I recommend you use `ZoneId`, `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` for your date and time work. They are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). If for older Android, you can use java.time through desugaring. Don’t use the outdated and cumbersome `Date`, `Calendar` and `TimeZone`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my desktop Java I get `CET` and `CEST` as you had expected. Which is your default time zone? (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`.) And which is your default locale? Time zone abbreviations may vary by locale.

Comment: Using your winter timestamp `Instant .ofEpochMilli(1701687285000L) .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Budapest")) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z", Locale.forLanguageTag("hu")))` yields `CET`. And `CEST` if instead i use your summer timestamp.